# Different accuracy for different rng values

Tags: classification, svm, supervised-learning, matlab, accuracy

While tuning the SVM classification model in Matlab, I came across the rng function in matlab in which seed (stabilizes the random shuffling of the data in the algorithm) is changed. When the function called is rng(1) then I am getting one accuracy value (99%). When it is changed to rng(2) then I am getting another value (57%). So there is a huge change in accuracy as visible. What does this mean? Am I training it wrong? 

The train and test set correct rate (in %) that I am getting with different runs without changing rng are(train,test)
(96, 82.8)
(94.6, 95.3)
(96, 85.9)
(96, 90)
(95, 95)

Comment: What are the testing errors of both?  Nothing can be said by just looking at the training errors. Maybe `rng(1)` is better than `rng(2)` or maybe it is overfitting.

Comment: @Dawny33 So does this mean that there is overfitting? A good model should have the same accuracy for any rng right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The training errors in this dataset has a huge difference (99% vs 57%). So, maybe the one with the `rng(1)` split has overfitted your dataset.

> So there is a huge change in accuracy as visible. What does this mean?
>   Am I training it wrong?

The huge change might be due to overfitting. (Also, judge the model through validation curves, and then fit a model which balances the bias-variance plot.)

Comment: made a small change in the question. Let me know whether still there is over-fitting or not

Comment: @Rishika No, I don't think there's any overfitting there. But, that's without changing the rng value, right?

Comment: yes. This is without changing rng

Comment: @Rishika The model looks good to me, then :)